# Spring Boot Application Error Handling Always Returns Content-Type of application/xml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot REST service that has Spring Security enabled.  When I attempt to access an endpoint or resource that requires authentication in order to access, I get the following response:

```
>> GET https://mysite/secure-endpoint
>> Content-Type: application/json
>> ... (other request headers)

<< HTTP 401 Unauthorized
<< Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
<< ... (other response headers)
<< Body:
<< <UnauthorizedException>
<<     <error>unauthorized</error>
<<     <error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description>
<< </UnauthorizedException>
```

Note that I have made this request with requested content-type of "application/json".  Spring returns it with "application/xml".  How do I configure Spring error handling to respect the `Content-Type` request header?

Comment: Can you post your request and exception handler screenshot. It will give more clarity to find

Comment: *Note that I have made this request with requested content-type of "application/json".* That only says that your reqiest contains JSON. You have to add an `Accept`header, too.